# I hope I could ... or I hope I can ...?

Tags: prepositions

I hope I could do something / I hope I can do something / I would like to do something.
Please tell me which one is more polite and what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hope I could do something.

I would use this sentence to describe a hypothetical contingency: “If my neighbor were in danger, I hope I could do something.”

> I hope I can do something.

Something needs doing.  “The dog's leg is caught in the net! I hope I can do something.”  This is not really an *offer* to help, but more of an observation to a friend.

> I would like to do something.

This is what I would say if I see that there is much work to do but I do not know the best way to help.